# How to sort components of the local classes?

Tags: oop, refactoring, abap

In ABAP class builder it is possible to sort the lists of attributes and methods?

Since I often work with the big local classes I wonder how I could sort my method and attribute declaration in there. I'm quite sure there is no standard tool for this, but maybe somebody has written a utility or invented some other hack to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using the ADT? The outline view can be sorted AFAIR...

Answer (score 0):

I already tried this and could not find it how to sort.

You can use menu in SE24: GOTO->PUBLIC/PROTECTED/PRIVATE SECTION to see all methods/attributes (like a local class).

This way is faster to find a methods or attributes in big classes.

Comment: SE24 is not in charge. I am working with local defined classes in a report.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is by design and I actually prefer to structure/sort methods and attributes, putting them in a logical context to each other and being able to add enhanced or simplified methods right to the other one, instead of them being overlooked by others. Methods are stored like in this order in the system/source.

There might be something that helps you: The object list applies a sorting to methods and attributes. You can open it with the menu path Utilities > Display Object List or the corresponding button.

You may also consider playing with the Class Builder settings (Menu Utilites > Settings > Class Builder) and the filter options to make it look better for you.

Comment: As I said, I'm working with local classes that can not be reviewed using SE24. They make part of a report and are defined in there. So the class builder is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the methods into a new order and they will show in the new order.
For example Go>Public section and sort the methods there, activate and see the new order.